# Using Python and ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table

Is it possible to open a Python file on ArcGIS and use ArcGIS information (from attribute tables) in routines of this Python file? If it´s possible, how can I do?

Comment: Please add more information to your question. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Add some examples / code or images if necessary.

Comment: This time I don't have yet nothing to show here because I'm starting my work. First I wanted to know how can I open a python file, with some functions and calculations on arcgis. 
Then, I think that´s possible to export arcgis data to excel files and work in python with this files, but I wanted to know, if it is possible using data from attribute tables, for exemple, directly from my functions and calculations of the python file.

Comment: Look at the help documentation. There are python examples for virtually every help topic. Open the Python Window (Geoprocessing Menu) and give one a try.

Comment: Have you tried to open the Python window?  Have you tried following the documentation for using arcpy in Python scripts?

Comment: Not yet.. I'm going to see this documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can add a python file in ArcGIS, you can load the file to view it.

> The Python window is an interactive Python prompt that is useful for quick execution of Python functionality. However, code that has already been written to a Python file can also be loaded into the Python window by clicking in the Python prompt section and clicking Load Code, and then modified if needed and executed.

This is how the python window looks in ArcGIS

[image]

You can read more here on ESRI's [webpage](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/python-window.htm)

In regards to using python in the attribute table, I would suggest using the Field Calculator through the options of the field headers in the attribute table, you can learn more [here](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//005s0000002m000000)

Comment: I tryed to open and load a python script at python window and i got expected results. In this case, I was using values of my python script. But now I need to load and solve the same python script with values of the attribute table... How can I do this?